# How did Victor Creed become Sabertooth, and can he heal from injuries like this?

Tags: marvel, x-men, wolverine

In the movie [*X-Men Origins: Wolverine*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Men_Origins%3a_Wolverine) Victor Creed, Wolverine's half brother, falls off the top of the Reactor and his fate is not shown. In the X Men movie series, he is shown as Sabertooth.

- Does Victor Creed have the same healing power as the Wolverine, saving him during the fall?
- How did Victor become Sabertooth?

Answer (score 7):

**Victor Creed is a mutant with a very similar healing factor to Logan's. A fall from any height would have no long term effect on his overall survival under normal circumstances. You would have to vaporize his body to be rid of him permanently.**

In addition to his healing factor he is larger and stronger than Logan but lacking Wolverine's adamantium skeleton, the difference in their strength is offset by Wolverine's adamantium claws and reinforced skeleton.

His codename [Sabertooth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabretooth_%28comics%29) was given to him when he was part of the Weapon X supersoldier program. A covert operations agency which recruited and created soldiers with mutations or special abilities to perform various (read this as lethal) strikes against undesirable enemies.

The character has had an inconsistent history due to multiple revisions in his history, sometimes giving him specialized abilities and other times taking them away. Once he and Wolverine became regular sparring partners, his healing powers were increased to make them the equal of his enemy.

#### Sabertooth's powers:

> - Sabretooth is a mutant with a number of natural mutant powers and artificial improvements to his physiology. His primary mutant power was an accelerated healing ability that allowed him to regenerate damaged or destroyed areas of his body and cellular structure far beyond the capabilities of an ordinary human. He could regenerate organs such as missing eyes and large portions of flesh.
> - Sabretooth's natural mutant attributes stemmed from, at least partially, his accelerated healing factor. This "healing factor" also granted him virtual immunity to poisons, most drugs, toxins, and diseases, and limited immunity to the fatigue poisons generated by his own body. The unique regenerative qualities of his healing powers and "age suppression factor," Sabretooth's natural aging process, caused him to age at an unusually slow rate. While he was of an unknown advanced age, Sabretooth had the appearance and vitality of a man in his physical prime.
> - The depiction of Sabretooth's powers has evolved with his treatments by various writers. His healing power, in particular, was introduced as a retcon. When he became Wolverine's frequent antagonist, Sabretooth started being depicted as possessing a healing factor comparable to his foe's.
> - In other, earlier appearances, Sabretooth was not depicted as possessing such a power. In The Spectacular Spider-Man vol. 1 #116, he was incapacitated when his face was severely wounded, and did not display any accelerated healing ability. In issue #119 of The Spectacular Spider-Man, a still badly scarred Sabretooth returned, and his wounds reopened when he was hit in the face by the Black Cat. **--[Wikpedia: Sabertooth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabretooth_%28comics%29).**

- He also possesses superhuman strength, speed and reflexes superior to an Olympic-level athlete. His strength varies widely depending on his writer. His sensory organs including his sense of smell, sight and taste are all heightened making him capable of tracking a man by scent if necessary. He also has claws capable of rending soft metals, stone and human bones.